# Comparing two text files

Tags: linux, awk, perl

I have a text file like this.

```
2XKJ;2XKK;  B0V9T6
2XKJ;2XKK;  B0VP98
3TSG;   D3X610
```

and i have another file having PDB IDs.

```
2XKJ
2XKJ
2XKJ
2XKK
```

I want a output like this

```
2XKJ B0V9T6 B0VP98
2XKJ B0V9T6 B0VP98
2XKJ B0V9T6 B0VP98
2XKK B0V9T6 B0VP98
```

how to get this output using `perl` , `awk` or linux

Comment: why `B0VP98` should be skipped?

Comment: Ohh so sorry ..the output should be like ..2XKJ B0V9T6 B0VP98
2XKJ B0V9T6 B0VP98
2XKJ B0V9T6 B0VP98
2XKK B0V9T6 B0VP98

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F ';[[:blank:]]*' '
  !file1_done {for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) val[$i] = val[$i] " " $NF; next}
  {print $1 val[$1]}' file1 file1_done=1 file2
```